# Substitute signed version of file only when tagged

Tags: performance, python-3.x

I have a database that contains many files, and each one of those files contains many tags that relate to the file in some form.

Some of those files need to have a digital signature applied to them and due to reasons unrelated to the question I need to store the original files that don't have the signature applied. I store the file with the exact same tags as the original but apply another tag to the signed file marking it as signed.

When the files are displayed to the end-user I want to fetch all of the relevant files **but** if a file has a digital signature applied to it I only want to show that certain file and not the *original* file.

I've tried replicating this with the code example below. The main function I'm concerned with is `get_files_with_tags_any` and as far as I'm aware, this code works as intended but my main concern is optimization / or generally if there is a better way of going about it.

```
class Tag:
    """
    A single tag object with a name and an id
    """
    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id

class TaggedFile:
    """
    This represents a single file in the system that can contain many tags
    """
    def __init__(self, name, id, tags):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.tags = tags
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        tag_builder : str = ""
        for tag in self.tags:
            tag_builder += f"[{tag.name}] "
        return f"({self.name} {tag_builder.strip()})"
    
    def exclude_compare(self, other, exclude_tag):
        """
        Compares two TaggedFiles and returns True if they are the same, excluding the exclude_tag
        """
        self_excluded = [tag for tag in self.tags if tag.id != exclude_tag.id]
        other_excluded = [tag for tag in other.tags if tag.id != exclude_tag.id]
        return self_excluded == other_excluded
    
    def has_tag(self, tag):
        """
        Returns True if the TaggedFile has the tag
        """
        return tag in self.tags

class TaggedFileContainer:
    """
    Think of this container as a database which contains all the files in the system.
    """
    def __init__(self, files):
        self.files : list[TaggedFile] = files
    
    def get_files_with_tag(self, tag : Tag):
        return [file for file in self.files if file.has_tag(tag)]
    
    def get_files_with_tags_any(self, tags : list[Tag], preferred_tag=None):
        """
        Returns a list of TaggedFiles that contain any of the tags in the list,
        if preferred_tag is provided, it will exclude the files that have the exact same tags but are missing the preferred_tag
        """
        files_copy = [file for file in self.files if any(file.has_tag(tag) for tag in tags)]
        if preferred_tag is not None:
            all_preffered_tags = self.get_files_with_tag(preferred_tag) # Get all the files that have the preferred tag
            for file in files_copy:
                for preferred_file in all_preffered_tags:
                    # If the file has the same tags as the preferred_file, but is missing the preferred_tag, remove it from the list
                    if file.exclude_compare(preferred_file, signed):
                        if file.has_tag(signed):
                            files_copy.remove(preferred_file)
                        elif preferred_file.has_tag(signed):
                            files_copy.remove(file)
        return files_copy


animals = Tag("animals", 1)
people = Tag("people", 2)
places = Tag("places", 3)
signed = Tag("signed", 4)
dog = Tag("dog", 5)
cat = Tag("cat", 6)
alex = Tag("alex", 7)
bob = Tag("bob", 8)
park = Tag("park", 9)
school = Tag("school", 10)
unsorted = Tag("unsorted", 11)

file1 = TaggedFile("bobthecat.pdf", 1, [animals, cat])
file2 = TaggedFile("bobthecat_signed.pdf", 2, [animals, cat, signed])

file3 = TaggedFile("bobtheperson.pdf", 3, [people, bob])
file4 = TaggedFile("bobtheperson_signed.pdf", 4, [people, bob, signed])

file5 = TaggedFile("centralpark.pdf", 5, [places, park])
file6 = TaggedFile("harvard_uni.png", 6, [places, school])

file7 = TaggedFile("unrelated_file.pdf", 7, [unsorted])
file8 = TaggedFile("unrelated_file_signed.pdf", 8, [unsorted, signed])

file_container = TaggedFileContainer([file1, file2, file3, file4, file5, file6, file7, file8])

# All animals, all people and all places, prefer signed files
file_list = file_container.get_files_with_tags_any([animals, people, places], preferred_tag=signed)

expected_output = [file2, file4, file5, file6]

if file_list == expected_output:
    print("Success")
else:
    print("Failure")
    print("Expected: ", expected_output)
    print("Got: ", file_list)
```

I'm happy to clarify further/provide any more details if needed!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code is for, rather than how it works, per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask). Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: Thanks @TobySpeight , I think the updated title is way better